# Looping through datagridview column

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a datagridview and want to toggle the visibility of many columns, but not all.

like this

```
for (int i = 3; i >= 60; i++)
      {
         datagridview1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
      }
```

but this has no effect.
when i change the visible state by hand like

```
 datagridview1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
 datagridview1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
 datagridview1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
```

it works, but with the loop not.

Comment: Check the stop condition of your loop and comeback to us.

Comment: Will 3 ever be greater than or equal to 60?

Comment: I want to toggle the colums from 3 to 60. But not the number of columns is the problem.

Comment: @FireBlast - try figuring out how the for loop you posted will **actually** work. Place a breakpoint inside the loop and see how many time it is hit you get.

Comment: @FireBlast I understand what you are _trying_ to do, I am simply pointing out that your loop does _not_ do what you want it to.  Take another look, **will 3 ever be greater than or equal to 60?**

Comment: you simply have the wrong operator in your loop declaration. `>` greater than _vs_ `<` less than. your current loop declaration implies you want to do something `for` as long as `i` is `>=` `greater than or equal to` `60`. You start `i` at `3`. Right there your condition is false because 3 is `<` `smaller than` `60`. you want `<=` instead of `>=`

Answer (score 0):

Ok time to spoonfeed... people are pointing to your stop condition in the for loop.

Yours:

```
for (int i = 3; i >= 60; i++)
  {
     datagridview1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
  }
```

What it should be:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 60; i++)
  {
     datagridview1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
  }
```

Try the difference yourself: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for_ex